# How to loop checkboxes?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox

I have 20 checkboxes named checkbox1 to checkbox20.

I would like to record the username in column B when each checkbox is checked.

For example, when a user clicks on checkbox1, B1 would populate the username, if checkbox2 is clicked, B2 would populate username.

I know how to write code for each checkbox and copy it 20 times. How can I combine them into one sub?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 20

    If Me.CheckBox & i = True Then

        Range("b1" & i).Value = Environ("USERNAME")

    Else: Range("b1" & i).Value = ""

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896038/access-to-activex-checkbox-value-with-name-of-checkbox-as-string) should be helpful.

Comment: You may create wrapper class and declare `Public WithEvents ctl As MSForms.CheckBox` and create `Private Sub ctl_Click()` or `Private Sub ctl_Change()` which will handle checkbox event, then create 20 instances of the class and assign each checkbox to each instance within loop. Note you should use Form Controls Check Boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In a module write following sub and then call this sub from `CheckBox_Click` event.

```
Sub LoopCheckBoxes()
Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box " & i).OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
            Range("B" & i) = Environ("USERNAME")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

See below screenshot to call above sub from checkbox click event.

[image]